# Display limited number of posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have displayed "news" category posts.

It is displaying all the posts, but how can i display latest 3 posts only?

Here is my code.

```
<div class="pt-news">
    <?php query_posts('cat=7','order=DSC');?>
    <?php $i=1;
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
        <div class="pt-newsdesc">
            <figure class="pt-post">
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </figure>
            <div class="pt-content"><?php the_content();?>
                <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php _e('Read More');?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        $i++;
        endwhile;
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: use posts_per_page in argument.

Comment: Used this <?php query_posts('cat=7','order=DSC', 'posts_per_page=3');?>. But this displaying all the posts

Comment: try this $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );

Comment: That is querry actually, where to use posts_per_page?

Comment: you have to use post per page in post argument array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display limited number of posts Used `posts_per_page` with  [query_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)
In `query_posts()` pass the argument array like bellow

```
<?php query_posts(array('cat'=>7,'order'=>'DSC','posts_per_page'=>3));?>
```

Or you can pass the Query string Like

```
<?php query_posts('cat=7&order=DSC&posts_per_page=3');?>
```

After this put your while loop code (No need to check auto increment variable  )

```
<?php 
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
        <div class="pt-newsdesc">
            <figure class="pt-post">
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </figure>
            <div class="pt-content"><?php the_content();?>
                <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php _e('Read More');?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        endwhile;
        ?>
```

Comment: It's pretty nice. Cool.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adjusting your while loop to :

```
<?php $i = 1; while (have_posts() && $i < 3) : the_post(); ?>
```

That should restrict it to 3 posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

---

```
<?php
                    $fpa = array(
                        'posts_per_page'=>8,
                        'post_type'=>'post',
                        'post_status'=>'publish',
                        'taxonomy'=>'category',
                         'term_ID'=>7
                    );
                    $fpq=new Wp_Query($fpa);
                    while ($fpq->have_posts()) {
                        $fpq->the_post();
                        $imagepath = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id());
                    ?>   Your content <?php } ?> //end while loop
```

---

You can edit code as you want place term_ID of category in which you want post. Also Posts_Per_Page will limit post number